# How to create a non block-scoped constant in js?

Tags: javascript, scope, constants

`const` creates a block-scoped constant. but how do you create a non-block-scoped constant? in Java this works by the `final` keyword.

You can't always define a `const` on the level you want. I'm talking about a constant that is on the global scope.

Comment: What do you mean by `non-block-scoped`? What do you want its scope to be? Just define the `const` at that level instead

Comment: you can't always define a const on the level you want. also  I'm talking about a constant that is on the global scope. for example. `const a = "constant"; this.a;//undefined`

Comment: Looking at your code example in your comment, you seem to have somewhat misunderstood what scopes are in JS. `const` and `let` declares scoped constants/variables (think *private*), they don't create properties on `this`. `this` in JS depends on the execution context and it's pretty much just a data object that has no connection to declared constants/variables.

Comment: I've not understood anything wrong here. The gist of my code example is that defining a  `const` in the highest level will still not create a property on the global object, and so it isn't identical to the `var` keyword. I agree, I should have used `window` instead of `this`, but they refer to the same object in the context of the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) as follows:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, "myVariable", {value: "initial value", writeable: false});
console.log(myVariable);

// Note that trying to change it doesn't work
myVariable = "something else";
console.log(myVariable);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It is the only answer that addresses the question - a constant variable that breaks out of its scope

Comment: I think it was because Object Property Descriptors wasn't what the OP asked about. And it's an overkill for this question. Probably the OP doesn't yet understand js to introduce a more advanced concept like that. OP it's trying to understand how scopes work yet.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira This is the solution OP was looking for. What he actually wanted was an immutable property on the global object, he just didn't phrase it that way because he didn't fully understand what scopes and contexts in JS are and seems to be approaching from a Java perspective

Comment: There are 2 downvotes and one upvote in your question. One downvote it's mine. As the OP chose your answer as correct, now I think my downvote was unfair. But as I downvoted yesterday the downvote is now locked unless the question is edited. If you want, make some edition in your answer and I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Variables can be defined in a few ways:

1. `var`: Scope is either global or contained within the function it is declared in. Variables can be reassigned at will.
2. `let`: Scope is restricted to the block in which it is declared (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). The value of the variable can be reassigned at will within the scope. Variables with the same name outside of the block scope are considered different vars. *Don't do this. It will confuse your code.*
3. `const`: Same restrictions as `let`, except once assigned the variable can't be reassigned.
4. function arguments: `(a, b, c) => {}` Basically the same as `var`, except since they are defined within a function that is the limit of their scope.

So if you want a constant that exists at a higher scope, simply declare it at a higher level. e.g.:

```
// declare it here
const color = '#cc0000';
const fn = () => {
  // instead of declaring the const here. In here, it will be limited to the scope of the function
}
```

Comment: What I wanted was something like `const` without the `let` restrictions. defining it on the highest level doesn't make it identical to a `var`, because it is not a property of the global object `const a = '#ddd'; this.a;//undefined`

Comment: I think you are still confused about scope in javascript. The global object will either be `window` for browsers and `global` for node.js. Your code example in your comment doesn't make any sense.

Comment: it means that `a` is not a property of the global object. I'm assuming `this == window`. so even if you declare a const in the highest level, it is not identical to a read-only variable

Comment: No, this never refers to the window or global scope. You can assign it as a property like window.a = 123 but “const a = 123” isn’t the same thing

Comment: `this` can and usually refers to the `window` object.

Comment: @JavaLearner No, it doesn't. Open the dev tools on this page. If you do `var xyz = 123`, then `window.xyz` returns `123`. However, this does not work when using `const xyz = ...` or `let xyz = ...`.

Comment: I'm *not* saying a `const` creates a property on the global object. I'm saying it doesn't. I said(1st comment) that defining a `const` on the highest level will not make it identical to a `var`, because `const`  does not create a property on the global object(unlike `var` which does). the gist of the code example was that a const will not create a property on the global object. `this` in that example refers to the global object, since the example is under the assumption that the code is on the highest level.

Answer (score 0):

Scopes in javascript are basically defined by objects, functions or ().

The top level scope is the window object. If you put it outside any function it will be there.

So if you want a non-blocked-scope, just define it outside any function, object, etc.